# Terms and greement page

Tags: user-profile

Hello i want to do like the page also add buttons like 
Is there a learning tutorial link or video or someone help
 Thank you

[image]

Comment: What are the buttons supposed to do apart from adding an item to a list?

Answer (score 1):

You have the terms and condition list - now read this list as the way we read any custom list either using SharePoint workflow, Nintex workflow or Microsoft Flow. And while sending an email notification to users about this "terms and condition" read the "**Terms**" description field, **Is Term Accepted?** checkbox field - then add these fields reference into the **send email notification action body** and in the send email send the **item URL** link - this way when the user gets the email will get the direct link to the list item and user action whether accepted or not accepted the terms, can be recorded in the same list.